# InDesign: Pasting shapes from one file to another makes shape change dimensions

Tags: adobe-indesign

Let's say I am designing two posters in InDesign. Both posters (the page size under File > Document Setup) are 36 inches wide, but they have different heights.

On one poster, I have a simple rectangle that is roughly 202p by 15p. It spans almost the whole 36 inch width of the page.

I copy and paste the rectangle from one file to another (also in InDesign). When I paste it, the height, color, and other attributes stay the same, but **the width is reduced to 7p6**!

Does anyone have any idea why copying and pasting a shape from one InDesign file to another would result in **just the width** being reduced so considerably? Thank you in advance.

*Poster 1: 36in by 36in page size*
[image: Poster 1: 36in by 36in page size]

*Poster 2: 36in wide by 72in high page size; zoomed in*
[image: Poster 2: 36in by 72in page size]

Comment: Documents have different resolution?

Comment: I don't believe InDesign documents have a set resolution. (See this page: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2363699)